# Why will pressing 'false' not break this java loop?

Tags: java

I have tried breaks and changing the `==` to a `!=`. This is a logic error purely, as everything works apart from the loop never ending.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Math;   
public class NumGuess
{
public static void main(String [] args){
    boolean anotherGame = true; 
    
    int random = (int)(Math.random()*(20-0+1)+0);
    int guesses = 5;
    int userGuess = -1; 
    anotherGame = true;
    int invGuess = 0;
    
    while(anotherGame == true){
        guesses = 5;
        userGuess = -1;
        random = (int)(Math.random()*(20-0+1)+0);
        invGuess = 0;
        while(random != userGuess && guesses > 0){
            userGuess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 0 and 20."));
            while (userGuess < 0 || userGuess > 20){
                System.out.println("Enter an integer between 0 and 20.");
                userGuess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 0 and 20."));
                invGuess++;
            }
        
        guesses--;
        
            if (random > userGuess){
               System.out.println("Higher!");
               System.out.println("You have "+guesses+" tries left.");
            }else if(random < userGuess){
               System.out.println("Lower!");
               System.out.println("You have "+guesses+" tries left.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
            }
        }
        if (guesses == 0 && random != userGuess){
            System.out.println("You have run out of guesses! The correct number was "+random+" .");
        }
        System.out.println("You had "+invGuess+ "invalid guesses.");
        int anotherGameInt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
        "Play again?", "Please select",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (anotherGameInt == 1){
            anotherGame = true;
        }else{
            anotherGame = false;
            
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post. Did you check the value of `anotherGameInt` ?  Side note: you can use `while(anotherGame)` instead of `while(anotherGame == true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
        "Play again?", "Please select",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

returns `JOption.YES_OPTION` (1) for Yes and `JOption.NO_OPTION` (0) for no.

You can verify that with a `System.out.println( anotherGameInt );` after the call

Comment: You should use the constants JOptionPane.YES and JOptionPane.NO instead of  the integers. If not for clarity, then for the possibility than the JDK may change the values of said constants.

Comment: Will update - I've never actually used Swing, so hey, I learned something too =)

Comment: I actually looked up the values for JOptionPane.YES and JOptionPane.NO in the openjdk source, so we both did. :p